# Window close on keypress?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, window, quit

I've been trying to find the answer to this with no look, I want to exit a unity game window (build not the game preview in the developer) here is a snippet of my code,

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape)) {
            Application.Quit();
        }

    }
```

This doesn't exit the window and I cant see why, any ideas?
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Sorry, im new to unity, this is my first game and im not familier with c#, how would i do that?

Comment: Just to make sure, it is finding the method ok and everything, right? Your program is going through it?

Comment: The rest of the code works but when I press escape nothing happens, even in console.

Comment: Just to ensure that the event isn't getting swallowed, can you use http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html to log a message to verify that you're intercepting the Escape key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the example given for [Application.Quit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.Quit.html) in the documentation

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I used what Dylan Corriveau said but to no luck, so i tried making a Js file and used the example from unity documents and it works now, thanks.